# UIImagePickerController distorts when app goes to background after recording Video

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

UIImagePickerController after recording video and in Editing Screen app goes to background and returns and the UI distorts as following.

[image: Distorted Image]

Any thoughts as to how to fix this. Or is it a known issue?
Following is the presentation code:

```
self.imagePickerController= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.delegate  = self;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

if(self.mediaType==MediaTypePhoto){
    self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

}else if(self.mediaType==MediaTypeVideo){
    self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    self.imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration=30.0f;
}
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this? if so, how? i'm having a similar issue when backgrounding a preview of a photo. when it returns, it shows all these extra controls and i can only tap cancel, which isn't ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently its a known issue. Only way is to launch video editor controller after picking/record the video. Sorry.

Comment: Hey! No worries! Thank you so much for following up!